# How to SHSetLocalizedName with a hard coded string?

Tags: windows, winapi, internationalization

I want to localize a shortcut and have come across this API SHSetLocalizedName() which takes a path to an executable and a resource ID. However, I want to use a string instead. It looks like it just writes to desktop.ini:

```
[LocalizedFileNames]
Test.lnk=@program.exe,-101
```

I played with it manually and I can just do this:

```
[LocalizedFileNames]
Test.lnk=Localized Name of Test Shortcut
```

Does anyone know a programmatic way of doing this? I really don't want to write to desktop.ini myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A hard coded string is the opposite of localization!

The point of `SHSetLocalizedName` is to have various parts of the start menu and some special folders (My documents etc.) display in a language that matches the users current UI language. To do this the string has to be a resource in a PE file so that the magic of multiple versions of a resource in different languages can work.

If you always want a specific name you can just rename the file. If you can't do that (you don't have write access or you are trying to trick the user) then perhaps this is not something you should programmatically be doing?

`SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings` knows how to change some values in desktop.ini but this string is not one of them. I believe using `WritePrivateProfileString` is the only solution...

Comment: ...also keep in mind that desktop.ini files have a special undocumented mode where some of the strings are UTF-7. `WritePrivateProfileString` does not understand this. Hint: https://zhidao-baidu-com.translate.goog/question/341709721.html?qbl=relate_question_7&_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yeah, I understand why it should be a resource in a PE file. However, our l10n process is set up in a somewhat "unique" way. We are not putting localized strings in resources. Instead, we are doing localization at runtime. I.e. the code detects the locale and look up localized strings with an ID and the locale. It's basically reinventing the wheel, I know.

So I'm trying to work around it by setting the display name of the shortcut at runtime too. Therefore I already have a localized string.

Comment: Set up [MUI Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/mui-resource-management#resource-configuration-data) normally and then use `SHSetLocalizedName` at runtime.